# Truffle Ropsten Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js fails with: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: truffle, ropsten, truffle-migration

> Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
>   transaction s manually.

So I'd checked  TxHash transactions manually, is here:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x3b5415de9584f43aa6155843a64e453a49189e16fc83cf00e2323935c045f460

```
truffle(development)> migrate --network ropsten
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying SafeMath...
  ... 0x9eb2ce16e8ed3e0dbb4a7e286a148f5c8dbca7233cfa49a61a02cc6df6214725
  SafeMath: 0x29373c7174c28927a127a156f4f4e1ea4ba89e0c
  Deploying Ownable...
  ... 0x20ea24cf646cb77e11ea35861f073486e2a392ffbe04b0f86766b48bb696dd89
  Ownable: 0x656f2084ff1916a887e138248452ae93b15fb74d
  Deploying Pausable...
  ... 0x0ada99f10d0e25ad37929cf7f2ab03f41d10a84e47dbc4dec83a1db40b5e2560
  Pausable: 0xed152244733a6d06679d9c5f9e6ba9afd970ff22
  Deploying BasicToken...
  ... 0x8b253db846b5c4411ac9dbb0c85654416a4e0010f016317b8faff4322d227bb6
  BasicToken: 0xcd4460ca0f93f078cafbbc4b7ddfa9d95f4c3530
  Deploying StandardToken...
  ... 0x3b5415de9584f43aa6155843a64e453a49189e16fc83cf00e2323935c045f460
  StandardToken: 0x678fd6ebdbb9dbbb961384c89bcc856c726a04ba
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transaction
s manually.
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at C:\Users\ROBERT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\.
-deployer\src\actions\deploy.js:16:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

> Standardtoken has been deployed successfully despite the error but the
>   process has been stopped and not complete deploy PatadiseToken.sol and
>   ParadiseTokenSale.sol.

**1_initial_migration.js ,
Works fine!**

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

**2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    // Use the accounts within your migrations.
    //console.log("Accounts: " + accounts);

    var userAddress = accounts[1];

    deployer.deploy(SafeMath);
    deployer.deploy(Ownable);
    deployer.link(Ownable, Pausable);
    deployer.deploy(Pausable);

    deployer.deploy(BasicToken);
    deployer.link(BasicToken, SafeMath);
    deployer.link(BasicToken, ERC20Basic);

    deployer.deploy(StandardToken);
    deployer.link(StandardToken, BasicToken);
    deployer.link(StandardToken, ERC20);

    deployer.deploy(ParadiseToken, userAddress);
    deployer.link(ParadiseToken, StandardToken);
    deployer.link(ParadiseToken, Ownable);
    deployer.link(ParadiseToken, SafeMath);

    var time = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

    var monkey = 1234;

    deployer.deploy(ParadiseToken, accounts[1]).then(function() {
        return deployer.deploy(ParadiseTokenSale, accounts[1], 10, 20, 1, time, 2, 15000, ParadiseToken.address);
    });

};
```

I think the problem is in **2_deploy_contracts.js**

**truffle.js** is here:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var infura_apikey = "<My key is here> "; 
var mnemonic = "<My MetaMask Seed Phrases is Here>";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
    provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://127.0.0.1:8545/"),
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten:  {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/" + infura_apikey),
      network_id: 3,
    }
  },
};
```

**testrpc output:**

EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2)

```
HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      venue denial battle taxi park army into reform spice situate frie
nd mango
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Listening on localhost:8545
```

I'm using **mnemonic MetaMask Seed Phrases**

**Truffle compile works fine !**

> ParadiseToken.sol and ParadiseTokenSale.sol is here:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xbe1121b96da695cbe68cf8e41f2fba6ea9eb80e9#code

Could someone point out why is like that. Is here an obvious error. Did I miss something?
Thank You, Robert.

Comment: apparently something wrong with `ParadiseToken` deployment, but I don't see what exactly. I would write unit tests or try to deploy via Remix, it can help to find a root cause.

Comment: Are you suppose to deploy imported contracts? (e.g. SafeMath). I'm using SafeMath and not deploying it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same error. In my case, it turned out that I forgot to set a value which is passed to constructor of a contract.